# Erro Bundler::GemRequireError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Quando tento lançar o rails server, surge o alguém sabe como proceder?

```
  Erro (Bundler::GemRequireError  

  /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
        from /home/gabriel/secondExample/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/gabriel/secondExample/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /home/gabriel/secondExample/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.4/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/gabriel/secondExample/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/gabriel/secondExample/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

A gem `uglifier` é um wrapper para o código JavaScript. Para poder executá-lo, você precisa ter o NodeJS (ou outro ambiente de execução JavaScript) também instalado na máquina.

Comment: cara, muito obrigado,depois de instalar o nodeJS to conseguindo lançar o comando de boas agora!